# Most promising new JSRs?

Tags: java, jsr

Fairly recently I have picked up a very useful web service framework, [Jersey](http://jersey.dev.java.net) (JAX-RS aka jsr-311; and its rock start implementation),  and a nifty validation library [Hibernate Validator](http://validation.hibernate.org) ("Bean Validation API", jsr-303).

Both of these jsrs are relative new-comers, which makes me wonder what else I may be missing -- given that there are hundreds of JSRs, with various level of progress, activity and potential, it is not easy to track them all.

So beyond 2 I have mentioned, what else do others consider promising and worth paying attention to?

Answer (score 3):

[`JSR-291`](http://www.osgi.org/JSR291/HomePage) : Dynamic Component Support for Java™ SE

---

Based on OSGi model, it would have been very interesting to have it integrated in Java.

But the [`JSR-277`](http://tech.puredanger.com/java7#jsr277) was finally selected (Java Module dependencies)... [before being dropped](http://alblue.blogspot.com/2008/11/rise-and-fall-of-osgi-and-jsr277.html) from the current JDK7 implementation.

In the meantime, there are [plenty of OSGi frameworks out there to play with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560794/what-osgi-container-do-you-recommend) ;)

---

As mentioned in the article "Representations of module dependencies":

> One of the key differences between JSR 291 and JSR 277 is the way in which module dependencies are represented, satisfied, and managed.
>
> [...] a more important difference relates to the need to be able predict the behaviour of a collection of modules. This is crucial when managing the dependencies of modules.
>
> - With **JSR 291**, an **external management system is able to read the dependency declarations in each module** and apply the rules in the specification to determine how these modules will be wired up, whether there are any missing dependencies, and, if there are, how such dependencies could be satisfied.
> - With JSR **277** the position is quite different when import policies are used. The **only way to determine the behavior of an import policy is to execute it**. But even then, there is no guarantee that the import policy will give the same result each time it runs. Also, if there are missing dependencies, it is not feasible to examine the import policy to determine how the missing dependencies could be satisfied

Comment: Agreed, interesting -- I kind of like OSGi, although only used it lightly so far (and converting some libs to run as proper OSGi bundles).
I have also wondered why the seeming NIH syndrome from JSR process part (i.e. OSGi predates alternatives, but was largely ignored within its domain). Oh well, that's happened before (log4j vs J.U.L for example)

Answer (score 1):

The ones I would like to see implemented more often in mobile handsets are JSR-239 OpenGL-ES Binding (with the nifty NIO buffers) and JSR-256 Sensor API (which at least bears some relationship with OSGi).